# select values of Cascading two dropdownlists from Gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, drop-down-menu

I have two dropdownlist and one Gridview, I want to select two Dropdownlists by select the row from Gridview. the problem is the first Dropdownlist is working, but the second is not.[image]

the dropdownlist that shows (mobile) works and selected according to gridview row selected. 
however, dropdownlist (galaxy) does not select the one we select from Gridview. here is the code which we wrote on page load,the first gridview is working but not the second.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

```
  please try this code
   protected void Grid_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       GridViewRow row = gvSummary.SelectedRow;
       string name= row.Attributes["Name"].ToString());
       string brandName = row.Attributes["brand_name"].ToString());
        DropDownList1.SelectedValue = name
        DropDownList2.SelectedValue = brandName; 

     }
```

Answer (score 1):

[image]

this is the error, which the [name] is not recognized

Comment: please try this code
   protected void Grid_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       GridViewRow row = gvSummary.SelectedRow;
       string name= row.Cells[6].Text;
       string brandName = row.Cells[7].Text;
        DropDownList1.SelectedValue = name
        DropDownList2.SelectedValue = brandName; 

     }